# LFS chroot cannot find /usr/bin/env

Tags: linux, shell, path, chroot, chroot-jail

I am building Linux from Scratch (guide version 10.1). Everything compiled without any errors, but I am now stuck at the step where it requires me to enter the chroot environment (section 7.4). My command is the following:

```
chroot "$LFS" /usr/bin/env -i \
HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" \
PS1='(lfs chroot) \u:\w\$ ' \
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin \
/bin/bash --login +h
```

It fails with the following error:

`chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory`

I have checked the following things:

$LFS points to the correct path

/dev, /run, /proc, /sys, /dev/pts and /dev/shm are all correctly mounted

/usr/bin/env exists

/bin/bash exists

/bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash

/bin/bash and /usr/bin/env have all their dependencies installed to /lib and /lib64 (checked using ldd)

Also, I want to point out that I am doing this build on x86-64, for x86-64, on Ubuntu 20.04 using Linux kernel 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! It was a bad symlink (/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 pointed to the absolute path on the host system, not relative to the LFS root, /lib/ld-2.36.so). It is such a shame that chroot gave me such a misleading and vague error message, instead of clarifying what and where went wrong. I changed the link, and now it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I crushed same problem but I couldnt understand what do you mean by
`(/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 pointed to the absolute path on the host system, not relative to the LFS root, /lib/ld-2.36.so)`
Could you explain more information about solution ? and how to change link ? And I want to poing that I am building x86-64 operation system.I found this at LFS11.0
[5.5. Glibc-2.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djIHf.png) 
Host usr/bin/env:

> COLORTERM=truecolor
> DISPLAY=:0.0
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> LANGUAGE=
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
> TERM=xterm-256color
> XAUTHORITY=/home/kali/.Xauthority
> LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
> MAIL=/var/mail/root
> LOGNAME=root
> USER=root
> HOME=/root
> SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
> SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
> SUDO_USER=kali
> SUDO_UID=1000
> SUDO_GID=1000
> LFS=/mnt/lfs
> COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1
> POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
> DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
> SHLVL=1
> PWD=/usr/bin
> OLDPWD=/home/kali
> LESS_TERMCAP_mb=
> LESS_TERMCAP_md=
> LESS_TERMCAP_me=
> LESS_TERMCAP_so=
> LESS_TERMCAP_se=
> LESS_TERMCAP_us=
> LESS_TERMCAP_ue=
> _=/usr/bin/./env

LFS usr/bin/env:

> PWD=/
> HOME=/home/lfs
> TERM=xterm-256color
> SHLVL=1
> PS1=${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$
> LFS_TGT=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
> LC_ALL=POSIX
> LFS=/mnt/lfs
> CONFIG_SITE=/mnt/lfs/usr/share/config.site
> PATH=/mnt/lfs/tools/bin:/usr/bin
> _=./usr/bin/env
> OLDPWD=/home

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1079177)

Comment: But my question is same as this question so I just want to get attention of writer of this post. Thus he/she can response me more quick then asking new question.If I am wrong please say me cause I am new and I dont wanna break any rules of this website. And at the same time I cant comment his/her answer cause of my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

@lorinet3 I ran into the same problem. I checked and the links are relative.

```bash
$ echo $LFS
/home/sayan/lfs/lfs_filesystem
$ exa -l $LFS/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx 27 root  6 Jun 11:43 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 27 root  6 Jun 11:43 ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 -> ../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I am following LFS 11.1 guide in x86_64 machine. I still get the same error. What else can be broken?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).